# Get input values from html file with thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to send a checkout POST, for my application, and I need to set the address and the payment type using HTML. But I don't know how to get the values and put them in my Checkout object. My current version gets an error at the html page, "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'checkoutOrder' available as request attribute"
Here is the html and object:

```
 <form action="#
         th:action="@{/checkout}"
         th:object="${checkoutOrder}"
         method="POST">


         <label> Enter Address:</label>
                <input type="text"
                       th:value="address"
                       name="address"
                       class="form dropdown"/>
                <br>

                       <label> Payment Method: </label>
                      
                      <select  th:field="*{paymentMethod}"
                               style="width:200px;"
                               class="form-select-lg mb-3"
                               name="paymentMethod">

                       <option class="dropdown-item active"
                               th:value="'Cash'"
                               th:text="Cash"/>

                       <option th:value="'Card'"
                               th:text="Card"/>
                       </select>

                <div class= "col">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger p-3 mt-2"
                                name="submit"
                                type="submit">Checkout</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

```
@Data
public class CheckoutOrder {

    private int id;
    private String address;
    private String paymentMethod;
    private List<OrderItem> orderItemList;
}
```

I want to have the RestController return a json object including the address and value of the html page. Here is the RestController:

```
RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CheckoutController {

    private final IUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final OrderService orderService;

    @PostMapping("/checkout")
    public ResponseEntity readcheckoutOrders(@ModelAttribute("checkoutOrder")
                                   CheckoutOrder checkoutOrder,
                                   @AuthenticationPrincipal Authentication authentication){

        User user=userDetailsService.getCurrentlyLoggedUser(authentication).getUser();
        List<OrderItem> orderItemList = orderService.findOrderByUser(user);
        checkoutOrder.setOrderItemList(orderItemList);

        return new ResponseEntity(checkoutOrder, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

And the response is :

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "address": null,
    "paymentMethod": null,
    "orderItemList": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "quantity": 2,
            "menu": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Burger",
                "description": "Burger Description",
                "url": "https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/19/ea/8d/f2/the-burger.jpg",
                "price": 30.0
            },
           
            "subtotal": 60.0
        }
```

Can you help me in getting the address and the payment method from html in this json object?

Comment: You might want to read up on [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/).

Comment: When returning your HTML page with the form, let's name it form.html, are you initializing `checkoutOrder` in the controller? before `return "form"`, are you adding `model.addAttribute('checkoutOrder', new CheckoutOrder)` ?